# The flood of "nvidia drivers + 16.04" questions

Tags: discussion

There is already a bunch of "I installed Nvidia drivers and now Ubuntu is borked" questions. What do we do with this?

I've only found two useful answers;

- Disable secure boot; this seems to enable some people to use their Nvidia graphics card.
- Uninstall the Nvidia driver.

https://askubuntu.com/search?q=nvidia+driver+16.04

Any idea how to move forward? Do we make one Canonical question for nvidia + 16.04 or one question for each "symptom" (one for blank screen, one for login cycle, ..)

Comment: There's already a canonical blank screen question that includes taking nvidia out as one options - so that reduces your question surface.  I'ld wait for the next point release of LTS before deciding on canonical answers, as the bugs may be ironed out rather quickly.

Comment: @Zacharee1 did one aswell [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics) it is.

Comment: @Videonauth Do these instructions also apply to intel+nvidia (optimus) laptops?

Comment: @Galgalesh not sure to be honest i have no means on trying it.

Comment: @videonauth I'll try it out and let you know ;)

Comment: @videonauth It works! Although disabling secure boot is a very important step, otherwise the Nvidia driver will not be loaded correctly. The process for disabling secure boot is not straightforward. I'll make a guide with pictures of how to do it.

Comment: yeah best to add it to that que then. but good to know

Comment: @Galgalesh If it's not already too late, would you mind adding disabling Secure Boot as an answer on my Q&A?

Comment: @Zacharee1, what Q&A are you talking about?

Comment: @Galgalesh Videonauth linked to it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with new kernels DKMS modules do not load.

That's why people can't use the drivers with Secure Boot on.

I wrote [a Q&A for it](https://askubuntu.com/q/762254/167850) and hope someone tests the solution. I do not have Nvidia on an UEFI machine.

But it should fix the DKMS issue.

Answer (score 1):

Any flood of questions around the same problem should be dealt with in the same way:

1. Make sure the best example of one of these questions is answered. Even if that's "This is a bug, this is what's happening, this is where you can subscribe to track its progress"
2. Dupe-Close future instances against that good example.
3. Sip on a Mai Tai, you're done.

Pilot6's Q&A seems as good as any (it *could* be better, eg link to active bugs) so I'd suggest closing against that unless a better version appears.